# Login & Logout using KeyChain in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, keychain, appdelegate

I  am developing an App with User Login and Logout  screen , At first time when enters show login screen it has user id and after that user has to move and enter the password if it is success then move to apps next screen .Then if user comes at second time i don't want to show the User id screen , i want to show the Password screen to enter the password and move to apps next screen ,I want to store userid and password in keychain .I don't about the keychain process .

I have used insurer defaults only till now .And there is one logout button in the password screen .If user logout , and then coming to the app at that time i need to show user id screen .i have designed the ui ,but i got stuck in the coding ,because i want to do this in app delegate class.i don't have much knowledge in this .Please help me to do this ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The UICKeychainStore framework is great for this. It makes storing things in the keychain just as easy as using NSUserDefaults.
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore

```
UICKeyChainStore *keychain = [UICKeyChainStore keyChainStore]; 
NSString *username = @"kishikawakatsumi@mac.com"; 
NSString *password = keychain[username]; 
if (password) {
    // If found password in the Keychain,
    // then go to second page 

} 
else {
    // If not found password in the Keychain,
    // then go to initial login page
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    InitialViewController *initialVC = (InitialViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"InitialVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = initialVC;
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks @iOess , i want example on how to present the userid screen on first time and how to present the password screen on second time ,Please help me to do this ...

Comment: where i have to use the keychain...whether in app delegate or in my first view controller ?

Comment: Please helpme...for keychain what i have to do ?is there any framework i need to add or no..Please help me with brief example